# Hard disk shows by BIOS, not on Linux (lsblk, fdisk...)

Tags: hard-disk, bios

I have a rather old Seagate **hard** disk (ST3500320NS 500G) which has been working for years and today it is **no longer seen by Linux**. **The BIOS sees it** though.

It is well possible that the disk is dead, but I am surprised for the following reasons:

1. **The disk is seen by the BIOS and not by Linux**. `lsblk` does not list it, thus `fdisk -l`, `gparted` don't see it either.
2. This arrived *just after* I changed my video card this morning. However, after the change, the disk did show up on Linux *once*.

Side notes:

- The video card works no problem and is fully recognized
- I am using Linux Mint 20.3
- I have 3 disks: a SD disk for `/`, and 2 HDD. The SD disk and one of the hard disks (a Western Digital) work fine. Only the Seagate Hard disk does not show up.
- I can't mount the disk as Linux does not see it: I don't even have something like a `/dev/sdX` for it.
- There is no message concerning the Seagate hard disk in `dmesg`
- To be perfectly exact, the BIOS does not see the disk all the time. Usually, it fails to see it after a soft reboot, but sees it ok after a hard reboot.
- I ran a Seagate test utility on a USB disk (actually, it boots a Linux on a USB drive and runs tests). All tests failed for this HD: SMART fails, generic fast test fails etc - I tried the "fix" utility which fails also for the disk.
- The BIOS uses AHCI for SATA disks (I saw that was an issue on another forum).

Any idea?

If the disk is dead, actually it was part of a LVM2 volume. Is there a way to mount the LVM volume without that dead disk?

Comment: "_it was part of a LVM2 volume_" - what kind of part? RAID1 (mirroring) or just the default "another place to put stuff"?

Comment: Welcome, did you try removing the video card and see what happens? Did you recheck *all* the connections after manipulating the hardware?

Comment: ...or booting from a USB recovery distro?

Comment: No, it's the default LVM2 type, where I use different disks to hold data. Not mirrorred, nor RAID 5 or anything like that.

Yes, I tried with the previous video card. I also tried the disk on a different SATA port, and also with a different SATA cable.

I used the SeaTools recovery USB distribution of SeaGate (it's a seagate tool). All tests failed, so I tried the "long fix". After that, it's better: the disk is now seen and mounts on Linux, but there are so many read errors that it's very slow to backup data... I suppose there's not much more I can do.